# Renaming a folder in git branch while someone makes changes in master

Tags: git

I have folder named X in git master branch. I want to replace it and its content. So I created a branch, renamed folder X to Y, created a new folder X and started working on its content.

Meanwhile someone added a file to folder X in master branch.

Now I am ready with my changes and I merge my branch to master. The result is that all the files from X are transferred to Y except the ones that were added after I made my branch and its a total mess.

How to avoid this kind of a situation? What is the correct way to replace a folder while someone else might be working on it?

Answer (score 0):

merge the branches, create a new branch,  `mv <badfolder> <good folder>` `git add .` `git commit -m 'your words here'` `git push`

jobs done.